# Passing Objects between different Windows in a java based tool application

Tags: design-patterns

I am designing a tool application that requires different windows passing objects not just messages at run time. I am also new to design patterns. However, since this application is not designed for network problems I was wondering if there are/is any design patterns such as router pattern for making this communications.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93View%E2%80%93Controller) and [Observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) design pattern. Both this patterns can help with the communication between the windows. They use a event notification mechanism to send messages(or objects) to all the listeners that are registered with the observable object.